# Python - Tkinter fix object position

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im currently testing around with python GUI and have made a script that takes 2 entered numbers from 2 textfields and upon a button press generates a block of labels (e.g. i enter 4 and 5 so it generates a 4x5 field of labels)

but now i want to do this: when i generate objects, i want to prevent them to
- move
- overlap
my current objects (buttons, textfields).
i can kind-of figure something for the overlapping, but every time i generate new stuff, everything moves around. Can i set a specific field in the grid to be "reserved" so that new stuff never goes in there?

this is my current attempt - as you can see, its not overlapping anymore, but if the snowflakes are generated, the textboxes and buttons still "jump" apart for a small distance

EDIT: the "jumps" are due to the font size of the added snowflakes - that still leaves my question on how i prevent this, as i dont want to be limited to small font sizes

```
from tkinter import *
wide = 0
deep = 0
entrytext = "test"
window = Tk()
window.title("test")
window.geometry('1000x1000')


ent = Entry(window)
ent.grid(column=0, row=1)

def GetClicked():
    global wide
    wide = ent.get()
    wide = int(wide)

btn2 = Button(window, text="Width", command=GetClicked)
btn2.grid(column=0, row=2)

ent2 = Entry(window)
ent2.grid(column=0, row=3)

def GetClicked2():
    global deep
    deep = ent2.get()
    deep = int(deep)

btn = Button(window, text="Depth", command=GetClicked2)
btn.grid(column=0, row=4)

def WingBut(column,row):
    lbl = Label(window, text="T", font=("Wingdings", 15))
    lbl.grid(column=column, row=row)
def clicked(wide,deep):
    h = 0
    j = 0
    while h in range (deep):
        i = 0
        h += 1
        while i in range(wide):
             if i > 2 or j > 5:
                 WingBut(i,j)
             i += 1
             if i == wide:
                 j += 1


btn = Button(window, text="Buttonspam",font=("Arial", 10),command=lambda: clicked(wide,deep))
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)






window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could try and use padding by passing `padx` and / or `pady` to `grid`. In when you do `Label(...).grid(padx=10, pady=20)`

Comment: Adding a sample of your code might help understanding your problem better.

Comment: added it, test it out to see what i ment - the objects do a little hop upon new objects being generated

Comment: Nothing happens when I click any of your buttons. Maybe it's because the indentation of your code seems broken.

Comment: ah maybe i should have explained that - you have to enter numbers into the 2 text boxes, then press the "width" and "height" buttons to change the variables to that number and THEN press the big button to generate the snowflakes (yes, the 2 buttons are kind of redundand, ill move their function to the big button sometimes i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the textboxes and buttons still "jump" apart for a small distance

This is due to the resulting size of the dynamically added labels (those labelled "T") being taller than the current row height for each row. Because the row size must increase to accommodate the new label, the other widgets in the same row are also resized so that the overall height for the row is consistent. That resize is causing the jumping effect.

One way to correct it would be to reduce the font size of the "T" labels. Try setting it to 10 and the problem should go away.

Another way to solve it would be to set the `minsize` for each row to be the height of the tallest widget in the row, e.g. the "T" label widget height.

```
for row in range(5):
    window.rowconfigure(row, minsize=36)
```

You can add the above code before you call `window.mainloop()`.

I selected 36 because this makes the rows a minimum of 36 pixels high, and this is sufficient on my system to display the "T" without causing the row to resize.

If you don't want to hardcode the `minsize` you could calculate it dynamically.

```
dummy = Label(window, text="T", font=("Wingdings", 20))
dummy.grid(row=0, column=0)
dummy.update_idletasks()        # seems to be required to get rendered size
height = dummy.winfo_height()
dummy.grid_forget()             # we don't want users seeing this widget

for row in range(5):
    window.rowconfigure(row, minsize=height)
```

That's one way to do it. Possibly there is a better, more direct, way using the font itself, but you can research that if you're interested.

Comment: aw, thats exactly what i was expecting but kind of disappointing - i assume it could be possible to "frame" the area with the buttons and textboxes? having to reduce the font size is kind of a bummer here, a cleaner fix would probably be to "split" the grid - but the minsize does work out too i guess, it at least feels better. thanks for advise